# How do I replace a variable in a polynomial?

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-manipulation, replacement

How do I substitue `z^2->x` in the following polynomial `z^4+z^2+4`?

```
z^4+z^2+4 /. z^2->x
```

gives

```
z^4+x+4
```

Comment: wow, are you guys telling me that the most advanced computer algebra software in the world cannot do a simple replacement of one variable for another without the user having to do some very unintuitive workarounds?

Comment: see http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42121/how-to-substitute-the-following-conditions-into-an-expression

Comment: z^4 + z^2 + 4 /. z^y_Integer -> x^(y/2) gives 4+x+x^2

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The reason why the replacement doesn't work is that replacement rules are not mathematical replacements, but pure structural replacements. Therefore the replacement `z^2->x` just looks for occurrences of the pattern `z^2` and replaces that with `x`. Now `z^4` doesn't match that pattern.

Also note that rules operate on the internal form, which doesn't always match the displayed form. For example, one would expect `a-2b /. 2b->c` to result in `a-c`, but it actually results in `a-2b` again, because internally the expression reads `Plus[a, Times[-2, b]]` (you can see that by applying `FullForm`), while `2b` is `Times[2,b]`.

To do the replacement wanted, one has to use a method which is aware of the mathematics instead of just the structure. One possibility is

```
Solve[p==z^4+z^2+4 && x==z^2, {p}, {z}]
```

which means "Solve the equations given for p while eliminating z". The result then is

```
{{p->4+x+x^2}}
```

Note that the curly braces around `z` are mandatory because otherwise Mathematica interprets it as domain, resulting in an error message because `z` is of course no valid domain. Also note that the documentation page of Solve omits the possibility of giving a list of variables to eliminate as third argument (at least I didn't find it). However, you'll find it in a [Mathematica tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/EliminatingVariables.html) on eliminating variables (but there they use the third argument without braces, which at least for me results in an error message, as written above).

Answer (score 19):

```
In[409]:= PolynomialReduce[z^4 + z^2 + 4, z^2 - x, {z, x}][[2]]

Out[409]= 4 + x + x^2
```

This is similar to the `Solve` approach in that both use algebraic means to effect the substitution. But one can be a bit more general using `PolynomialReduce` (by taking advantage of term orders, say).

For further detail on this approach, might have a look at some responses to these questions:

- [Question on "smart" replacing in Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6210321/)
- [How to reduce the number of independent variables in Mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5008764/)

Answer (score 14):

```
 z^4 + z^2 + 4 /. z^(a_Integer) -> x^(1/2 a)
```

yields

```
4 + x + x^2
```

Answer (score 10):

How about using `Eliminate` and `Solve`?

```
Solve[Eliminate[{expr == z^4 + z^2 + 4, z^2 == x}, z], expr]
```

Alternatively we can use the third argument of `Solve` to [tell it which variables should be eliminated](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/EliminatingVariables.html):

```
Solve[{expr == z^4 + z^2 + 4, z^2 == x}, expr, {z}]
```

Note that the braces around `z` are mandatory, otherwise it will be interpreted as the [domain](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Solve.html). (Thanks @celtschk!)

Comment: I thought `Solve` had an option to eliminate some variables while solving, but I couldn't find it.  So I used `Eliminate` explicitly.

Comment: In http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/EliminatingVariables.html `Solve` is given as `Solve[eqns, vars, elims]`. And indeed, `Solve[p==z^4+z^2+4&&x==z^2,{p},{z}]` gives `{{p -> 4 + x + x^2}}`. Note that the braces around `z` are mandatory, or it will be interpreted as domain.

Comment: @celtschk Thanks!  I remembered something like that, but I didn't add the braces, so it didn't work

Answer (score 5):

I'd do

```
z^4 + z^2 + 4 /. z -> Sqrt[x]

(* 
 -->  4 + x + x^2
*)
```

In this particular case, at least (which of course may not work in more general situations, for example with odd powers of `z`, since I randomly picked the sign)

Comment: It wasn't random. It's the principal value, just like [Artes' solution](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/557/34).

Comment: @Simon Well, ok, I agree.

Comment: The easiest way.

Answer (score 3):

In the same vein as Daniel's answer (since the functions are definitely related):

```
First[GroebnerBasis[{z^4 + z^2 + 4, z^2 - x}, x, z]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using rules one could,

```
rule = {z^s_ /; s >= 2 /; Mod[s, 2] == 0 -> x^(s/2)}
l //. rulesk
```

> 4 + x + x^2