# Why is an integer not considered as a real?

Tags: expression-test

Please consider the following:

```
zeros={0.,0};   
data={1, 0., 0}; 
DeleteCases[data, #]&/@zeros
Head/@zeros
(*{Real, Integer}*)
(*{{1, 0}, {1, 0.}}*)
```

For my understanding all integers (e.g. `0`, `2`) are element of the real numbers (e.g. `0.00000`, `2.00000`). So why would Mathematica not delete all zeros form `data`.

I know from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7463/is-this-the-most-efficient-way-to-round-approximate-integers-to-integers-while-l) that one can solve the `DeleteCases`-problem via `DeleteCases[Rationalize@data,0]` but this is not the point here.

**EDIT**

The following test may explain my problem slightly better:

```
sets={Integers,Reals,Complexes};
test=Table[Element[j, i], {i, sets}, {j, zeros}];
(*{{False, True}, {True, True}, {True, True}}*)
```

`test` returns as expected that `0` is element of `Integers`, `Reals` and `Complexes` for which reason I would expect for `DeleteCases[data, #]&/@zeros` the following result:

```
{{1}, {1, 0.}}
```

For the latter `0.` can not be deleted from `data` because I called *delete all 0-Integers* whereas in the first case all zeros can be deleted as I called *delete all 0-Reals*.

**Note:**
Instead of `0` and `0.` we could use also `2` and `2.`. The value does not matter.

Comment: Are you trying to do `DeleteCases[data, 0 | 0.]`?  As far as I can tell your example works as expected.  With `/@` you are only deleting one type of zero at a time.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The answers to your quoted question do not answer my question. Please consider the following: `zeros = {0, 0.};
sets = {Integers, Reals, Complexes};
eTest=Table[Element[zeros[[j]], sets[[i]]], {i, 3}, {j, 2}]` However, Mathematica returns for `0==0.` `False` as J.M. pointed out in his question.

Comment: I shall reopen this question, but I encourage you to expand and clarify it because as it presently reads it looks like a duplicate.

Comment: Incidentally, try: `Table[Element[j, i], {i, sets}, {j, zeros}]`

Comment: I agree with Mr.Wizard that this is a duplicate. Please explain why exactly it is not and how the other answers do not answer your question. As for `0==0.`, you should read up the documentation for `Equal` and `SameQ`... it's fully covered between the two.

Comment: @rm-rf I agree, the question is a duplicate but as I mentioned the answers do not match. Please see edit.

Comment: `Element` is a mathematical operation, which is why it (correctly) says that `0` is an element of `Integers/Reals/Complexes`. However, `0.` is a floating point representation of zero and is not an exact integer, hence `False`. It certainly is an element of `Reals`, and by extension, an element of `Complexes` which is a superset of `Reals`, which is why it returns `True`. `DeleteCases` uses pattern matching and relies on the heads (or the `FullForm`) and _does not_ do a mathematical comparison. This is something you need to get comfortable with in order to use Mathematica effectively.

Comment: @rm-rf This is the answer I was looking for :) If you guys still think we should close this post please do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Element`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Element.html) (of) is a *mathematical* operation, which is why it (correctly) says that `0` is an element of `Integers`, `Reals` and `Complexes`. However, $0.$ is a floating point representation of zero and is not an exact integer, hence it returns `False` for `Element[0., Integer]`. On the other hand, `0.` certainly is an element of `Reals`, and by extension, an element of `Complexes` which is a superset of `Reals`, which is why it returns `True` for both these cases.

[`DeleteCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DeleteCases.html) uses *pattern matching* and relies on the heads (or the `FullForm`) and *does not* do a mathematical comparison, which is why `DeleteCases[list, 0]` will not remove instances of `0.` in `list`. The solution in this case is to either use `0 | 0.` as the pattern, or use `PossibleZeroQ` to test the elements of `list`:

```
DeleteCases[data, _?PossibleZeroQ]
(* {1} *)
```

The difference between mathematical operations and the pattern matching logic is something you need to get comfortable with in order to use *Mathematica* effectively. Another example of a [common mistake](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3463/5) is to use pattern matching to perform algebraic manipulations.

Comment: ...or, one might consider preprocessing the data: `DeleteCases[Chop[list], 0]`

Comment: @J.M. well, $10^{-11}$ is still not $0$, and going the extra length of using the second argument seems long winded :)

Answer (score 2):

DeleteCases uses the pattern matcher which matches against the FullForm of expressions. Just use Alternative:

```
In[]:= DeleteCases[{1, 0., 0}, 0. | 0]
Out[]= {1}
```

or a conditional pattern

```
In[]:= DeleteCases[{1, 0., 0}, _?(# == 0 &)]
Out[]= {1}
```

or

```
In[]:= DeleteCases[{1, 0., 0}, x_ /; x==0]
Out[]= {1}
```

This happens a lot with infinity be careful of the heads: `Infinity // FullForm` is `DirectedInfinity[1]`

Comment: A bit more on the `Infinity` part: using `Infinity` in replacement rules or patterns works just as expected, because both expand out to `DirectedInfinity` (for example: `DirectedInfinity[1] /. Infinity -> 1` and `Infinity /. Infinity -> 1`). The confusion, however, often occurs when one expects division by zero to occur, but then wants to disregard it and replace it with something arbitrary. In that case, it is not `DirectedInfinity` that's used, but `ComplexInfinity` and doing `foo /. Infinity -> bar` will not work

Comment: @rm: to catch all forms of `*Infinity`, one should then match against the pattern `_DirectedInfinity`, since `ComplexInfinity` is the same as `DirectedInfinity[]`.

Comment: @J.M. Yes, that is correct.