# How to transform an expression using algebraical instead of pattern rules

Tags: replacement, polynomials, equation-solving

I would like to transform rules algebraically. A very simple example would be: -

```
k^2 - 2 k x + x^2 /. {2*k -> 1}
```

This transforms to: -

$$k^2-2 k x+x^2$$

However, I would like it to return something more like: -

$$\frac{1}{4}- x+x^2$$

In fact, I am more interested in solving quadratic, cubic and quartic polynomials. For example, I am able to set the discriminant of a quadratic to zero as a rule since the solution of a quadratic is already in an expanded form: -

```
quadratic = a*x^2 + b*x + c
Solve[quadratic == 0, x]  /. { Discriminant[quadratic, x] -> 0 }
```

This yields the correct results: -

$$\left\{\left\{x\to -\frac{b}{2 a}\right\},\left\{x\to -\frac{b}{2 a}\right\}\right\}$$

To achieve something similar for the cubic one must expand the solution while also transforming the discriminant.

```
cubic := a*x^3 + b*x^2 + c*x + d;
ExpandAll[Solve[cubic == 0 , x]] /. { Expand[-27*a^2*Discriminant[cubic, x]] -> 0 }
```

This process requires some forward thinking and doesn't easily apply to a quartic.

I am hoping Mathematica has some built in transformation rules for substituting expressions algebraically (obviously assuming certain criteria, i.e field/ring etc..) Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: For the first part you can just do `k^2 - 2 k x + x^2 /. {k -> 1/2}`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks Yes, that's obvious. The point is that requires one to solve for k in the rule before using it. I am looking for an automated way of making these transformations.

Comment: I think I am also not getting it yet either, but maybe something like: k^2-2 k x+x^2/.Evaluate[Solve[2k==1,k]][[1]] ?

Comment: @chuy how would you expand that idea to discriminants?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3463/5

Comment: @bsdz, again I am not sure I really get the problem, but `cubic/.Evaluate[Solve[Discriminant[cubic,x]==0,a]]`

Comment: or rather something like: `Simplify[Solve[cubic == 0, x], Discriminant[cubic, x] == 0]` ? (not sure if that is what you wanted)

Comment: @PinguinDirk yes that seems to return the same result as the ExpandAll statement. Seems much better. Might take a while to run against a quartic on my laptop. Will investigate a little further. I will also investigate Eliminate mentioned elsewhere. Thanks.

Comment: And of [can i simplify an expression into form which uses my own definitions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3822/can-i-simplify-an-expression-into-form-which-uses-my-own-definitions).

Comment: And of the one noted by @rm -rf.

Answer (score 2):

I understand you want to transform the solution to an equation by imposing that it's solutions also satisfy another equation (discriminant = 0).

This is for the quadratic case : all output are equivalent, though the first one is the most familiar.

```
Solve[{quadratic == 0, Discriminant[quadratic, x] == 0}, {x, c}]
(* {{x -> -(b/(2 a)), c -> b^2/(4 a)}} *)

Solve[{quadratic == 0, Discriminant[quadratic, x] == 0}, {x, b}]
(* {{x -> -(Sqrt[c]/Sqrt[a]), b -> 2 Sqrt[a] Sqrt[c]}, 
   {x -> Sqrt[c]/Sqrt[a], b -> -2 Sqrt[a] Sqrt[c]}} *)

Solve[{quadratic == 0, Discriminant[quadratic, x] == 0}, {x, a}]
(* {{x -> -((2 c)/b), a -> b^2/(4 c)}} *)
```