# Replace an expression with a slightly tricky LHS transformation

Tags: replacement

I would like to make the substitution `x^(11*y) -> r` in the following equation

```
x^(11 *y^z) - 1
```

to end up with:

```
r^(y^(z - 1)) - 1
```

How can I do this in *Mathematica*?

Comment: `Replace` is most suited to structural transformations, not mathematical. So maybe another tool would be more appropriate (but I don't know what to suggest)

Comment: It is a little tricky to apply the principles in dupliate question and get what you want: `Simplify[x^(11*y^z) - 1 /. x -> r^(1/(11*y)), r > 0 && y > 0]`  Keep in mind *Mathematica* treats expressions as `Complex` by default.

Comment: @MichaelE2 thanks. looks good. Trying to test it against the other expressions I have.

Answer (score 4):

This gives the desired result:

```
Simplify[x^(11*y^z) - 1 /. x -> r^(1/(11*y)), r > 0 && y > 0]
(* -1 + r^y^(-1 + z) *)
```

If one examines the `FullForm` of the expression, one can see that the pattern `x^(11*y)` in the original replacement does not occur:

```
x^(11*y^z) - 1 // FullForm
(* Plus[-1, Power[x, Times[11, Power[y, z]]]] *)
```

In fact, it seems difficult to get rid of `x` with any replacement except one of the form `x -> ..`.  Luckily one can get `x^(11*y) ->  r` in terms of `x`.

---

The princples in the answers to [this related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3463/replacing-composite-variables-by-a-single-variable) might be tried, but they don't work as is.  You have to keep in mind

1. Mathematica treats expressions as `Complex` by default.
2. `Simplify` only returns an expression that has a lower `LeafCount`.

These yield the same leaf count (9):

```
LeafCount[-1 + r^y^(-1 + z)]
LeafCount[x^(11*y^z) - 1]
```

So the original expression is returned if one tries

```
Simplify[x^(11*y^z) - 1, x == r^(1/(11*y)) && r > 0 && y > 0]
```

assuming that *Mathematica* can even get to the desired expression.

One the other hand, `Eliminate` works well on polynomials but balks on this one, which has exponential functions in it:

```
Eliminate[{x^(11*y^z) - 1, x == r^(1/(11*y))}, x]

(* Eliminate::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Eliminate, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information. >> *)
```