# Replacing a sum of expressions

Tags: replacement

I have an equation which Mathematica solves but gives a huge output. However I notice in this output that the same expression occurs many times. Namely:

$E=864 a^6 - 432 a^4 b^2 + 54 a^2 b^4 - b^6 + 54 b^4 x^2$

where $a,b,c$ are constants. However this expression can appear in the form $-E$, $E^2$, $\sqrt{E}$, $4E$, ...

I'm struggling to tell Mathematica to make the replacement

$(864 a^6 - 432 a^4 b^2 + 54 a^2 b^4 - b^6 + 54 b^4 x^2) \space \to \space E$

wherever it appears.

All the ways I've tried (I'm not that handy with Mathematica I note) don't change output. Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a short example of an actual expression that your are truing to simplify.  Otherwise there is no way for us to tell if our solution will work in your case.

Comment: @JohnMcGee What do you mean? It's an incredibly long solution to an equation, and the expression in my question, $E$, appears many, many times. But as I say, it could appear as $-E$, $E^{15}$, $E^{1/3}$...

Comment: @JohnMcGee I mean I could provide a small portion of the output I need simplifying but I can't even follow the brackets and square roots of Mathematica because they're all so nested.

Comment: Closely related: [3463](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3463), [3822](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3822)

Comment: @user13223423 You can just copy and paste the expression to your question and we can just copy and paste it back to our notebooks. Use `Ctrl+Shift+C` and `Ctrl+V` to preserve space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must carefully define all desired / expected replacement cases. For example:

```
poly = 864 a^6 - 432 a^4 b^2 + 54 a^2 b^4 - b^6 + 54 b^4 x^2;

Clear[rep]

rep[p_] := p /. p :> p[[0]]@B
rep[Power[p_, n_]] := p /. p :> Power[B, n]
rep[Times[n_, p_]] := p /. p :> n B

rep[poly]
```

> B

```
rep[Log@poly]
```

> Log[B]

```
rep[1/poly]
```

> 1 / B

```
rep[poly*2]
```

> 2 B

```
list = {poly, Log@poly, poly^2, 1/poly};

rep /@ list
```

> {B, Log[B], B^2, 1/B}

I feel there should be easier solutions using the `Hold...`, `Unevaluated`, `Inactive` family. However, I can't find them.

Comment: There's a mistake in your code. For example `rep[2x]` returns `2B`.

Comment: @ChipHurst Thanks for your attention. I wouldn't call it a mistake. As a matter of fact, `2 x` should give `2 B`. Your spaceless `2x` doesn't exist in MMA (except as a `String`).

Comment: @ChipHurst BTW (I just noticed): Thanks for solving my `InverseFunction`-problem

Comment: This doesn't work for a lot expressions containing `poly`. For example, `rep[1 + x^2 + (1/poly)^3]` returns `B`. `rep[p_] := p /. p :> p[[0]] @ B` is what is causing this. It is too indiscriminate.

Answer (score 1):

One (potentially incorrect, but quick and dirty) way to do it is to instead make the substitution

```
864 a^6 -> E - (−432 a^4 b^2 + 54 a^2 b^4 − b^6 + 54 b^4x^2)
```

Also, do you really mean E?  E in Mathematica is the symbol for the base of the natural logarithm...

Comment: This is what I would do, but only in the case where the entirety of the expression is expected to boil down to some function of $E$ and not include any leftover $a,b,c,d,e$.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
poly = 864 a^6 − 432 a^4 b^2 + 54 a^2 b^4 − b^6 + 54 b^4x^2;

expr /. f_ /; PossibleZeroQ[poly - f] -> "E"
```