# Restrict Mathematica command to what is inside parentheses

Tags: simplifying-expressions, output-formatting, formatting

I have a bunch of expressions like this one:

$\frac{e^{-\frac{7 J}{2 k T}} \left(2 e^{-\frac{2 g H \mu _B}{k T}}+e^{-\frac{g H \mu _B}{k T}}-e^{\frac{g H \mu _B}{k T}}-2 e^{\frac{2 g H \mu _B}{k
   T}}\right)+e^{\frac{5 J}{2 k T}} \left(3 e^{-\frac{3 g H \mu _B}{k T}}+2 e^{-\frac{2 g H \mu _B}{k T}}+e^{-\frac{g H \mu _B}{k T}}-e^{\frac{g H \mu
   _B}{k T}}-2 e^{\frac{2 g H \mu _B}{k T}}-3 e^{\frac{3 g H \mu _B}{k T}}\right)}{e^{-\frac{7 J}{2 k T}} \left(e^{-\frac{2 g H \mu _B}{k T}}+e^{-\frac{g
   H \mu _B}{k T}}+e^{\frac{g H \mu _B}{k T}}+e^{\frac{2 g H \mu _B}{k T}}+1\right)+e^{\frac{5 J}{2 k T}} \left(e^{-\frac{3 g H \mu _B}{k T}}+e^{-\frac{2
   g H \mu _B}{k T}}+e^{-\frac{g H \mu _B}{k T}}+e^{\frac{g H \mu _B}{k T}}+e^{\frac{2 g H \mu _B}{k T}}+e^{\frac{3 g H \mu _B}{k T}}+1\right)}$

and I want to convert all the terms inside the parentheses, and not the terms outside, into hyperbolic trig functions, using **ExpToTrig** command, but I'm not sure how to do this. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Closely related: [What's the correct method to simplify exponentials?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8503/whats-the-correct-method-to-simplify-exponentials)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
x = E^-n (2 E^-1 + E^2) + E^n (2 E^-2 + E);

x /. Times[a_, b_] :> Times[a, ExpToTrig@b]
```

> E^n (E + 2 Cosh[2] - 2 Sinh[2]) + E^-n (2 Cosh[1] + Cosh[2] - 2
>   Sinh[1] + Sinh[2])

Comment: You beat me to it. (+1)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for acceptance @snowball. In cases like this one you should look at the `FullForm` of a simplified example (first line of my answer) to find the appropriate replacement pattern. For other, more complex cases, read f.e. http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/56975/replacing-a-sum-of-expressions/56989#56989