# Can I simplify an expression into form which uses my own definitions?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, faq, semantic-matching

This seems like a simple thing to do, but I couldn't find anything relevant from Mathematica documentation.

So suppose I have an expression:

```
a*b/(a + a*Cos[a/b])
```

And I have defined:

```
k=a/b
```

Now I want to simplify the expression above so that the simplify would use my definition of k in place of a/b in as many places as possible so that the final expression would look something like:

```
a/(k+k*Cos[k])
```

This was just a simple example I made up to demonstrate what I'd like to do, but I have encountered a similar situations many times every now and then.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Daniel Lichtblau and Andrzej Koslowski posted a solution in mathgroup, which I adjusted marginally. (I like to use german identifiers, because they will never clash with Mma builtins). That's the code:

```
SetAttributes[termErsetzung,Listable];
termErsetzung[expr_, rep_, vars_] := 
Module[{num = Numerator[expr], den = Denominator[expr],
        hed = Head[expr], base, expon},
  If[PolynomialQ[num, vars] && PolynomialQ[den, vars] && ! NumberQ[den], 
    termErsetzung[num, rep, vars]/termErsetzung[den, rep, vars], (*else*)
    If[hed === Power && Length[expr] === 2,        
       base  = termErsetzung[expr[[1]], rep, vars];
       expon = termErsetzung[expr[[2]], rep, vars];
       PolynomialReduce[base^expon, rep, vars][[2]],        (*else*)
      If[Head[Evaluate[hed]] === Symbol && 
        MemberQ[Attributes[Evaluate[hed]], NumericFunction], 
        Map[termErsetzung[#, rep, vars] &, expr],    (*else*)
       PolynomialReduce[expr, rep, vars][[2]] ]]]
];

TermErsetzung[rep_Equal,vars_][expr_]:=
  termErsetzung[expr,Evaluate[Subtract@@rep],vars]//Union;
```

Usage is like this:

```
a*b/(a + a*Cos[a/b]) // TermErsetzung[k b == a, b]
```

> a/(k (1 + Cos[k]))

The first parameter is the "replacement equation", the second the variable (or list of variables) to be eliminated:

```
a*b/(a + a*Cos[a/b]) // TermErsetzung[k b == a, {a, b}]
```

> {b/(1 + Cos[k]), a/(k (1 + Cos[k]))}

Comment: Thanks! This combined with FullSimplify seemed to do exactly what I wanted.

Comment: If you want to prevent name conflicts with built-in names the canonic method is to start your variable names with a lowercase letter. German names are no guarantee, they may still conflict with built-in ones (EigenSystem and GröbnerBasis are examples) and are less convenient for the majority of people here that do not speak German.

Comment: @Sjoerd in "normal" circumstances I always start with lower case letter, but for functions in my "helper-functions-package" I like Capitalize.

Answer (score 21):

This general question has been raised on the main StackOverflow site.  The answers to these questions may be helpful:

[How to reduce the number of independent variables in mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5008764/618728)

[Question on “smart” replacing in mathematica](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6210321/618728)

[How to perform a complicated change of variables for a polynomial (in Mathematica)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6074801/618728)

[Get mathematica to simplify expression with another equation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8073530/618728)

Look specifically at the answers by Daniel Lichtblau.

---

More questions on the topic here on Mathematica.SE:

[Can I simplify an expression into form which uses my own definitions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3822/121) (this question)

[How do I replace a variable in a polynomial?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/552/121)

[Replacing composite variables by a single variable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3463/121)

[Replace expressions with symbols](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/894/121)

[Reduce an equation by putting a new variable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10935/121)

[Find subexpression to minimize leafcount after replacment with temporary variable](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8787/121)

[Common subexpression from two expressions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/25132/121)

[Rewriting one expression using a variable representing another expression](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/49192/121)

[Replacing a sum of expressions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56975/121)

Comment: wow! An "answer" linking to other answers on the same question? You definitely are taking this to new heights :O

Comment: @rm-rf *New* heights?  The post is from two years ago. ;-p  This information *needs* to be *somewhere*; do you have a better idea?

Comment: Yes, I know that (see deleted comments) :) My only suggestion before was to not merge them, but I see that's now useless as well :P The merge made a link self-referential, hence my comment. In any case, I try to tell folks _not_ to post "link only" answers so I don't see why this answer should be treated differently. (Or should we start posting answers with only cross-links to other answers on related questions as well?) But I don't really care... the weather today is just too magnificent to not go outside!

Comment: @rm-rf Sorry, I didn't remember the full history of this.  I needed to refer to this answer and I found you had deleted the question it was attached to some time ago (which I don't disagree with).  Since the question was *already* deleted I didn't (and don't) see the harm in merging, so I popped my answer over here with a merge.  Regarding link-only answers I think *occasionally* they are OK, especially if the links are numerous and all to SE resources that wont go dead.  Nevertheless it was for that concern that I merged an old answer rather than posting a new one.

Comment: @rm-rf And I ran out of character space, but ***Merry Christmas!***

Comment: Merry Christmas to you too! :)

Answer (score 11):

In this simple example you can just use a rule. In more complex cases it might not be straighforward to generalize.

```
Simplify[a*b/(a + a*Cos[a/b]) /. a -> k b]

(* b/(1 + Cos[k]) *)
```

Answer (score 8):

Rephrasing your question, what you want is to eliminate a given variable by introducing another one. There are two ways to go about it:

- The first (and easiest) is simply to express you change in variable in a rule, such as `b -> a/k`, and use it in a call to `ReplaceAll` (aka `/.`). This gives the following code:

  > ```
  > In[1]:= a*b/(a + a*Cos[a/b]) /. b -> a/k
  > Out[1]= a^2/(k (a + a Cos[k]))
  > ```
- The second way, it is covered in [this Mathematica tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/EliminatingVariables.html). You can use `Eliminate` to that aim, but it might not do exactly what you intend. For example, in your example, it will actually go further than you intended:

  > ```
  > In[4]:= Eliminate[{U == a*b/(a + a*Cos[a/b]) && k == a/b}, a]
  > Out[4]= (-ArcCos[(b - U)/U] == k && b != 0) || (ArcCos[(b - U)/U] == k && b != 0)
  > ```

Comment: Actually you could follow that with `U /. First@Solve[%, U, Reals]`. I don't know if there are situations where that would be preferred to b.gatessucks's answer.