# Reduce an equation by putting a new variable

Tags: equation-solving, output-formatting, simplifying-expressions, algebraic-manipulation

I have the following equation given:

$$ (26-x)\cdot\sqrt{5x-1} -(13x+14)\cdot\sqrt{5-2x} + 12\sqrt{(5x-1)\cdot(5-2x) }= 18x+32. $$

In order to solve it, I want to substitute $t = \sqrt{5x - 1}-\sqrt{5-2x}$. This cannot be done directly but with this step the equation could be transformed in the form $(t-2)^3 = 0$, which can be solved easily.

Is it possible to make this substitution with Mathematica? The only thing I have achieved is to solve it directly with

```
Solve[(26 - x)*Sqrt[5*x - 1] - (13*x + 14)*Sqrt[5 - 2*x] + 
      12*Sqrt[(5*x - 1)*(5 - 2*x)] == 18*x + 32]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A standard approach for this kind of task uses `Eliminate`. It works nicely with polynomial equations, and even though neither this transformation : $\;\sqrt{5x - 1}-\sqrt{5-2x} \rightarrow t \quad$ nor the original equation : $ (26-x)\sqrt{5x-1} -(13x+14)\sqrt{5-2x} + 12\sqrt{(5x-1)(5-2x) }= 18x+32\quad$ are of polynomial types, nevertheless we can make some tricks to get exactly  $\;(t-2)^3 = 0$.

Defining

```
f[x_] := (26-x) Sqrt[5x-1] - (13x+14) Sqrt[5-2x] + 12 Sqrt[(5x-1)(5-2x)] - 18x - 32
```

terms like  : $\sqrt{(5x-1)(5-2x)}\;$ should be `PowerExpand`'ed  in order to get the lowest possible order of resulting polynomials (otherwise we would get a ninth order polynomial):

```
Eliminate[{ f[x] == 0 // PowerExpand, Sqrt[5x-1] - Sqrt[5-2x] == t}, x]
```

> ```
>  12 t - 6 t^2 + t^3 == 8
> ```

If we didn't play with `PowerExpand` we would use another definition of function $f$ yielding effectively the same result :

```
f1[x_] := (26-x) Sqrt[5x-1] - (13x+14) Sqrt[5-2x] + 12 Sqrt[(5x-1)] Sqrt[5-2x] - 18x - 32

Eliminate[{ f1[x] == 0, Sqrt[5x-1] - Sqrt[5-2x] == t}, x]
```

Now we rewrite the equation we've got `-8 + 12 t - 6 t^2 + t^3 == 0` in the following form :

```
TraditionalForm[-8 + 12 t - 6 t^2 + t^3 == 0 // Factor]
```

[image]

And this is indeed equivalent to our orignial function `f[x]` :

```
(t-2)^3 == f[x] /.t-> Sqrt[5x-1] - Sqrt[5-2x] // FullSimplify
```

> ```
>  True
> ```

**Edit**

It is remarkable that `f` being rather a complicated (complex also for real arguments) function has only one simple root :

```
Reduce[ f[x] == 0, x]
```

> ```
> x == 2
> ```

which implies `t == 2`. To make this result more understandable we can plot the contours of `f` in a complex domain :

```
GraphicsRow[ Table[ Show[
    ContourPlot @@@ { { g[f[x + I y]], {x, -2, 6}, {y, -4, 4}, Contours -> 37,
                        RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, 60 > g[f[x + I y]] > -60],
                        PlotLabel -> Style[ g[HoldForm @ f[x + I y]], Blue, 15],
                        ColorFunction -> "DeepSeaColors"},
                      { Re @ f[x + I y] == 0, {x, -2, 6}, {y, -4, 4},
                                              ContourStyle -> {Red, Thick}},
                      { Im @ f[x + I y] == 0, {x, -2, 6}, {y, -4, 4}, 
                                              ContourStyle -> {Cyan, Thick}} }, 
    Graphics[{ Thickness[0.01], Darker @ Green, Line[{{0.2, 0}, {2.5, 0}}]}]],

                    {g, {Re, Im, Abs}}]]
```

[image]

The color curves denote the following sets of points `z` in the complex plane

- red   ; where: `Re[ f[z]] == 0`
- cyan  ; where: `Im[ f[z]] == 0`
- green ; the set of `z` where `Im[ f[z]] == 0` restricted to the real domain.

One can easily see that these curves cross only at `z == {2,0}`.

We complement the plots of the function `f` restricting to the real domain only (here the green line denotes the region where the imaginary part vanishes):

```
GraphicsRow[
    Plot[{ Re @ f[x], Im @ f[x]}, {x, ##}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, PlotRange -> Automatic,
         PlotStyle -> { Thick, Thickness[0.008]}, AspectRatio -> 1.1, 
         Epilog -> { { Thickness[0.01], Darker @ Green, Line[{{0.2, 0}, {2.5, 0}}]},
                     { PointSize[0.023], Red, Point[{2, 0}]}}] &
    @@@ {{-3, 3}, {-.1, 3.5}, {0.7, 3}}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is a solution by hand with the help of Mathematica.  Put $t=\sqrt{5x-1}-\sqrt{5-2x}.$ 
We have
$$t^2=3x+4-2\sqrt{(5x-1)( 5-2x)}$$ 
And 
$$t^3=(14-x)\sqrt{5x-1}-(13x+2)\sqrt{5-2x}.$$
Put 
$$f(x)=(26-x)\sqrt{5x-1}-(13x+14)\sqrt{5-2x}+12\sqrt{5x-1)( 5-2x)}-(18x+32)$$
With the command Simplify in Mathematica, we have
$[(t-2)^3 - f(x)] = 0.$ That why, my question, I wrote "put" $t=\sqrt{5x-1}-\sqrt{5-2x}.$ But I can not write the code as Artes.

Comment: @minthao_2011 I added plots of the function `f` in order to make the problem easier to understand. I had to try a few ways to tackle this issue and this is not a simple problem in general. I find your question really interesting and I hope you'll gain more upvotes for it.

Comment: This method can be use to solve the system of the equations. For example
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
x^3 + y^3 = 2,\\
x^2 + y^2 -3xy=-1.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
f[x_, y_] := x^3 + y^3
Eliminate[{f[x, y] == 2 // PowerExpand, x + y == S, x*y == P}, {x, y}]
g[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2 - 3*x*y
Eliminate[{g[x, y] == -1 // PowerExpand, x + y == S, x*y == P}, {x, 
  y}]