# Adding a thick curve to a regionplot

Tags: plotting

Suppose we have the following simple RegionPlot:

```
f[x_] := 1 - x^2
g[x_] := 1 - 0.5 x^2
RegionPlot[{y < f[x], f[x] < y < g[x], y > g[x]}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

Now I'm trying to change the curve defined by $y=g[x]$ into a thick black curve, while leaving all other boundaries in the plot unchanged. I've tried adding the region $y=g[x]$ and playing with the plotstyle, which didn't work, and I've tried BoundaryStyle, which changed *all* the boundaries in the plot. Now I'm kinda out of ideas... Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can find what you are looking for here [Reduce an equation by putting a new variable](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10935/reduce-an-equation-by-putting-a-new-variable/10952#10952) or here [How do I solve this equation?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16897/how-do-i-solve-this-equation/16906#16906). These posts deal with `ContourPlot`  but you can do the same with `RegionPlot`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With

```
 f[x_] := 1 - x^2
 g[x_] := 1 - 0.5 x^2
```

You can use `Epilog` to add the thick line:

```
 RegionPlot[{y < f[x], f[x] < y < g[x], y > g[x]}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2},
            PlotPoints -> 50,
            Epilog -> (Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thick}][[1]]),
            PlotStyle -> {Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.4]],
                         Directive[Pink, Opacity[0.4]],
                         Directive[Green, Opacity[0.4]]}]
```

or a combination of `MeshFunctions`, `MeshStyle` and `Mesh` with a *small* value (somehow `0.` does not work):

```
RegionPlot[{y < f[x], f[x] < y < g[x], y > g[x]}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
           PlotPoints -> 50,
           Mesh -> {{0.00001}}, MeshFunctions -> {Abs[#2 - g[#1]] &}, 
           MeshStyle -> Thick, 
           PlotStyle -> {Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.4]], 
                         Directive[Pink, Opacity[0.4]], 
                         Directive[Green, Opacity[0.4]]}]
```

or `Show` to show the region plot with a second plot containing the thick line:

```
Show[RegionPlot[{y < f[x], f[x] < y < g[x], y > g[x]}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}, 
                PlotPoints -> 50,
                PlotStyle -> {Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.4]],
                              Directive[Pink, Opacity[0.4]],
                              Directive[Green, Opacity[0.4]]}], 
      Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 2}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Thick}]]
```

to get

[image]

Comment: Ah, I tried some stuff with Epilog but didn't know I could put a Plot function inside. This is perfect, thanks a lot!

Comment: @ScroogeMcDuck, my pleasure. Please note the pattern `Plot[...][[1]]` -- not `Plot[...]` -- on the rhs of `Epilog`. And, thank you for the accept. Btw, it is advised that you wait a while before accepting an answer to encourage alternative/better answers.

Comment: Alright, I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 4):

```
Show[
 RegionPlot[{y < f[x], f[x] < y < g[x], y > g[x]}, {x, 0, 2}, {y, 0, 2}],
 RegionPlot[y > g[x], {x, -0.1, 2.1}, {y, -0.1, 2.1},
  BoundaryStyle -> Directive[Thick, Black]],
 PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

[image]