# Simplify symbolic expression in terms of constants

Tags: symbolic

Say I have an expression $a+b+a\times b$ and I define $c:= a\times b$. How do I get *Mathematica* to write $a+b+a\times b$ in terms of $c$, i.e. $a+b+c$?

Comment: `Simplify[a + b + a*b, a == c/b]`

Comment: What about `a + b + a b /. a b -> c` ?

Comment: This is an oft-asked question with no simple answer.  Really we need a canonical Q&A that addresses many variations in one place.  Until that time here are [some links to related questions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11701/121).