# How to simplify expressions

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement

I read several similar posts but I have not found a solution yet. However, I think that my problem should be quite easy. So here we are.

Relations

```
Mt = M1 + M2;
x1 = -(M2/Mt)*R;
x2 = R*(1 - M2/Mt);
r1 = (x - x1)^2 + y^2;
r2 = (x - x2)^2 + y^2;
Ω = Sqrt[Mt/R^3];
```

---

```
V1 = -M1/(b1^2 + Sqrt[b1^2 + r1]);
V2 = -M2/(b2^2 + Sqrt[b2^2 + r2]);
Vt = V1 + V2;

Vx = D[Vt, x];
Vy = D[Vt, y];
Print["Vx = ", Simplify[Vx]]
Print["Vy = ", Simplify[Vy]]
```

My question is how to simplify the expressions `Vx` and `Vy`. Mathematica computes them correctly but I want to take into account the above relations, in other words, `Vx` and `Vy` should contain `Mt`, `r1`, `r2` and `Ω` in order to get the most simplified output.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

It seems that rules do not work in this case. For example if I set

```
rule1 = {Mt -> M1 + M2};
```

and apply it to `Vx`

```
Vx/.rule1
```

the output still contains `M1 + M2` instead of `Mt`. Same goes for `r1`, `r2` and omega.

Comment: A very common question.  I have gathered links to related questions here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3822/can-i-simplify-an-expression-into-form-which-uses-my-own-definitions#11701

Comment: @Mr.Wizard As I state in my post, before I ask this question I read most of the previous posts but none of the approaches worked in my case. Perhaps this is a different case (maybe more complicated expressions) and needs special treatment.

Comment: I assumed you had missed some of them since there are so many and they are scattered all about.  This question *appears* to be a duplicate in the conceptual sense and I was trying to keep there from being *more* questions on the topic if possible.  Can you confirm that you have indeed tried all the solutions from the linked posts?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes. In fact, in many of the linked posts the examples are very simple expressions, while in my case the expressions are much more complicated.

Comment: Reopened as requested.

Comment: Is `b1` and `b2` supposed to have any relation to the existing variables?