# Rewriting the set of equations in terms of new variables, using replacement rules when the expression contains partial derivatives

Tags: replacement

I am working with cumbersome equations, that contain a lot of terms. Here I will consider simple example:

```
v[x_, y_, t_] = {D[Ψ[x, y, t], {y, 1}], -D[Ψ[x, y, t], {x, 1}]};
r = {x, y};
II = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
Q = {{n1[x, y, t], n2[x, y, t]}, {n2[x, y, t], -n1[x, y, t]}};
p1 = D[Q, t] + v[x, y, t].Grad[Q, r];
eq1=p1[[1, 1]] + I*p1[[2, 1]]
eq2=p1[[1, 2]] + I*p1[[2, 2]]
```

As a result, I have two scalar equations (which I treat as expressions, omitting zero right hand side), `eq1, eq2`:

$n1_t+\Psi_y n1_x-n2_x\Psi_x+i(n2_t+\Psi_y n2_x+n1_x\Psi_x)$

$n2_t+\Psi_y n1_y-n2_y\Psi_x+i(-n1_t+\Psi_y n2_y+n1_y\Psi_x)$

I want to rewrite them in terms of a new variable, $n=n1+i*n2$. As a result, I should get:

$n_t+\Psi_y n_x+in_x\Psi_x$

$-in_t+\Psi_y n_y+in_y\Psi_x$

I calculated it on the paper, but it is easy to verify, that these are correct answers:

```
n[x_, y_, t_] = n1[x, y, t] + I*n2[x, y, t];
eq1r = D[n[x, y, t], t] +  D[Ψ[x, y, t], y]*D[n[x, y, t], x] +             
I*D[Ψ[x, y, t], x] D[n[x, y, t], x];
eq2r = -I*D[n[x, y, t], t] + D[Ψ[x, y, t], y]*D[n[x, y, t], y] + 
I*D[Ψ[x, y, t], x] D[n[x, y, t], y];
Simplify[eq1 - eq1r]
Simplify[eq2 - eq2r]
```

How can I do it automatically? Note, that it is not always possible to write the answer in terms of `n` and it's derivatives. Sometimes it could involve complex conjugate of `n`, or even `Re[n]` and `Im[n]`, which are `n1` and `n2` correspondingly.

Hope it is clear what I want. I tried to use simple substitution `./`, but I cannot make it work with `eq1/.n1[x,y,t]->Re[n[x,y,t]]`.

For example, the following equation can be rewritten in terms of `n` and it's coplex conjugate (and derivatives):

```
v[x_, y_, t_] = {D[Ψ[x, y, t], {y, 1}], -D[Ψ[x, y, t], {x, 1}]};
r = {x, y};
II = {{1, 0}, {0, 1}};
Q = {{n1[x, y, t], n2[x, y, t]}, {n2[x, y, t], -n1[x, y, t]}};
A = 1/2*(D[v[x, y, t], {r}] + Transpose[D[v[x, y, t], {r}]]);
Ω = 1/2*(D[v[x, y, t], {r}] - Transpose[D[v[x, y, t], {r}]]);
p2 = Simplify[(ξ*A + Ω).(Q + II/2)];
eq=p2[[1, 1]] + I*p2[[2, 1]]
```

Comment: Proposed duplicate: [(3822)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3822/121)

Comment: I would disagree. On the one hand, my problem is more straight-forward: It is always possible to express equation in terms of new variables, so that final answer doesn't contain old variables, unlike the question you provided. From another hand, I use more complicated definitions, going from real equations to complex equations. I was looking for more straight-forward solution.

Comment: You will notice that I did not close this question directly as I recognize room for disagreement.  However there are already many answers to similar questions, and you did not indicate that you have tried any let alone all of these.  In my opinion you should start there.  If you were to edit your question to explain that you have tried solutions X, Y, Z from posts ..., and they do not work or are not optimal because ..., then I suspect your Question will be reopened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your equations are filled with partial derivatives, and so your replacement rules also need to take this into account.  You were trying to do this,

```
Derivative[0, 0, 1][n1][x, y, t] /. {n1[x, y, t] -> Re[n[x, y, t]]}
(* Derivative[0, 0, 1][n1][x, y, t] *)
```

Instead, you need to format your replacement rule in terms of a pattern,

```
Derivative[0, 0, 1][n1][x, y, t] /. {Derivative[a__][n1][x, y, t] :> Re[Derivative[a][n][x, y, t]]}
(* Re[Derivative[0, 0, 1][n][x, y, t]] *)
```

So you can apply this to your equation now,

```
replacementrules = {
   Derivative[a__][n1][b__] :> Re[Derivative[a][n][b]], 
   Derivative[a__][n2][b__] :> Im[Derivative[a][n][b]],
   n1[b__] :> Re[n[b]], 
   n2[b__] :> Im[n[b]]};
eq1 /. replacementrules
(* Re[Derivative[0, 0, 1][n][x, y, t]] + Re[Derivative[1, 0, 0][n][x, y, t]]*Derivative[0, 1, 0][Ψ][x, y, t] - Im[Derivative[1, 0, 0][n][x, y, t]]*Derivative[1, 0, 0][Ψ][x, y, t] + 
  I*(Im[Derivative[0, 0, 1][n][x, y, t]] + Im[Derivative[1, 0, 0][n][x, y, t]]*Derivative[0, 1, 0][Ψ][x, y, t] + Re[Derivative[1, 0, 0][n][x, y, t]]*Derivative[1, 0, 0][Ψ][x, y, t]) *)
```

You can get the simplest form by using `ComplexExpand`

```
ComplexExpand[
 {eq1, eq2} /. replacementrules]
```

[image]

You can apply this to your final equation as well,

```
ComplexExpand[
 eq /. replacementrules]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This answers my question. Btw, after you used `replacementrules`, we can use `FullSimplify`. It will convert it to the desired form.

Comment: I would be even more happy, if you provide me a link to a resource that will explain, why `Derivative[a__][n1][b__] :> Re[Derivative[a][n][b]], ` works. I am not familiar, how this is supposed to work.

Comment: I am at home now, so typing this on mobile. Essentially, when you dou a rule replacement it is very literal, only replacing exactly what you type. But you can use a pattern to make a replacement that is more general. You can start [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PatternsAndTransformationRules.html), but you want to look at patterns and replacements, I'm sure there are good posts on here.

Comment: Actually, your answer is not quite correct: if you take `ComplexExpand[Re[n[x,y,t]]]`, you get `n[x,y,t]`, which is not correct (in my context). Should use FullSimplify

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
eq1 /. n1 -> (n[#1, #2, #3] - I*n2[#1, #2, #3] &) // Simplify
```

yielding

[image]

and

```
eq2 /. n1 -> (n[#1, #2, #3] - I*n2[#1, #2, #3] &) // Simplify
```

returning

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Thanks, very simple - but not completely what I need. Imagine, `eq1=n1[x,y,t]`. If I want to rewrite it in terms of a new variable, the answer should be `Re[n[x,y,t]]`. Your code will not generate this

Comment: @Mikhail Genkin I did exactly what you asked above.There is no universal answer to the question of this type, that would allow you to completely automatize the calculations. Anyway you will need to find the approach corresponding to the task.  Now you put a new question, and the approach must be different. For example: `n1[x, y, t] /. n1 -> (Re[n[#1, #2, #3]] &)`.

Comment: Ok, may be I was not very clear with my question.