# Replace subexpression that appears as inverse too

Tags: replacement

I have

```
eq=Sqrt[(g m)/h] Tanh[Sqrt[h/(g m)] t]
```

then I am trying to replace `Sqrt[m g/h]` by a symbol `v0`. Obviously, the rule `Sqrt[m g/h] -> v0` does only half the job as it does not replace inside the hyperbolic tangent with `1/v0`. Is there a simple trick I am missing? Or do I have to spell it out explicitly by hand with a rule `Sqrt[h/(mg)] -> 1/v0`

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [(3822)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3822/121)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 eq = Sqrt[(g m)/h] Tanh[Sqrt[h/(g m)] t] /. g -> v0^2*h/m // 
  Simplify[#, v0 > 0] &

(*  v0 Tanh[t/v0]  *)
```

Have fun!

Comment: Nice trick! I was hoping for something more automatic but I guess I could solve `Sqrt[m g/h] == v0` for one of the variable and then use your trick. And maybe write some generic code to do that.