# Replacing a expression in another expression with a Variable

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement

I want to set a symbol (or variable) for an expression. Here is an example:

```
A x^2 + C x + D
```

I want to reduce this expression to

```
x^2 + G x + D/A
```

but Mathematica can't do this way

```
A x^2 + C x + D /. C/A -> G
```

---

The above was just an simple example, but my problem is in complex expression like:

```
(c Kϕ Sin[(i π z)/l])/hw + (c EIw i^4 π^4 Sin[(i π z)/l])/(hw l^4) - 
  (c i^2 π^2 (-GJ + r0^2 P[z]) Sin[(i π z)/l])/(hw l^2) + 
  d Dw (6/hw^2 + β μ) Sin[(π z)/λ] + (c i π r0^2 Cos[(i π z)/l] Derivative[1][P][z])/(hw l)
```

and I want to replace some part like this:

[image]

and first expression convert to:

[image]

How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: I am marking this as a duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3822/121 -- unfortunately there is no robust built-in solution for this kind of thing but it has been brought up many times before and there are many partial solutions.  See my answer to that question for links to many more related questions.  Please try the solutions therein, and if they do not work edit this question to describe what you tried and what the result was, including a link to the source post.

Answer (score 0):

```
A x^2 + C x + D /. {A -> 1, C -> G, D -> D/A}
```

gives what you expect

Comment: tnx but i said that very simple example to find a way for that complex expression.

Answer (score 0):

The question is ambiguous, in that what variables (if any) are to be eliminated when introducing `H1` and `F` is not specified.  One course of action is to name the original expression `ex` and then perform,

```
Solve[H1 == (EIy β^2 λ)/2, EIy][[1, 1]]
Solve[F == (3 Dw λ)/hw^3 - Dw*(2 - μ)/(2 hw) λ β, Dw][[1, 1]]
ex /. {%, %%}
(* -((2 c F hw^3 (-(6/hw^3) + (β (2 - μ))/hw) Sin[(π z)/λ])/(λ (6 - 2 hw^2 β + 
   hw^2 β μ))) + d Kx Sin[(i π z)/λ] + (2 d H1 i^4 π^4 Sin[(i π z)/λ])/(β^2 λ^5) - 
   (d i^2 π^2 P[z] Sin[(i π z)/λ])/λ^2 + (d i π Cos[(i π z)/λ] Derivative[1][P][z])/λ *)
```

Comment: I edited my question. please look again. tnx

Comment: Please give your definitions of B1, etc in Mathematica format.

Comment: Also, `F` and `Q` are not in your final expression.  Is that intentional?

Comment: B1 = (GJ \[Pi]^2)/(2 \[Lambda] hw^2);
N1 = (Af r02  \[Pi]^2)/(2 \[Lambda] hw^2);
S1 = (Af \[Pi]^2)/(2 \[Lambda]);
H1 = (EIy \[Beta]^2 \[Lambda])/2;
F = (3 Dw \[Lambda])/hw^3 - Dw*(2 - \[Mu])/(2 hw) \[Lambda] \[Beta];
Q = (3 Dw \[Lambda])/hw^3 + Dw*\[Mu]/(2 hw) \[Lambda] \[Beta];

Comment: Because I have 2 expression and i just posted one expression. Is it necessary to send exact formula?

Comment: `Af` and `kx` also are missing.