# How can I use ReplaceRepeated (//.) in this case?

Tags: replacement, rule

Consider the following case:

```
(a^3*b) //. {a^2 -> c, a*b -> d}
```

instead of `c d` the output is:

```
(*a^3*b*)
```

How can I get what I want?

Comment: `Simplify[a^3 b, {a^2 == c, a b == d}]` will return `c d`. Replacement rules will look for a pattern match, and won't really consider the underlying math. Since `Power[a, 2]` is not present as such in `Times[Power[a,3], b]`, it does not get replaced.

Comment: So there is no way. Thanks.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3822/121

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you want to make the left hand sides of your rules as simple as possible.  A simple way of doing what you want is

```
(a^3*b) //. {a -> Sqrt[c], b -> d/a}
(* c d *)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
Last@PolynomialReduce[a^3*b, {a^2 - c, a*b - d}, {a, b}]
```

> c d

Or a more tricky

```
a^3*b //. {a^n_ :> c*Quotient[n, 2]*a^Mod[n, 2], 
  Times[r1___, a, b, r2___] :> Times[d, r1, r2]}
```

> c d