# Treat 2 variable as 1

Tags: equation-solving, variable

Is there anyway to treat two variable, that are a result of expansion, as one?

To use `Solve[]` I can do

```
Clear[x, z, y, eq]
eq = Expand[x (z + y)] /. x z -> xz
Solve[eq == 0, xz]
```

Is there anyway to solve directly like

```
Clear[x, z, y, eq]
eq = Expand[x (z + y)]
Solve[eq == 0, x z]
```

Comment: What about `/. x -> z`? Notice that `x z` is a multiplication.

Comment: @Kuba not sure, what you're getting at. Perhaps one could streamline OP's workaround somewhat like `Solve[equations /. x -> xz/z, xz] /. xz -> x z` taking out the not always reliable `Expand`

Comment: @LLlAMnYP I understood that OP does not want to define a relation but to consider `x` and `z` the same variable, therefore I suggested that. Then one can solve for `z` as there is only `z` for `z` or `x`.

Comment: @Kuba I should have been more clear. I was asking if there was a way to treat `xz` as a new variable, one that is different from both `x` or `z`.

Comment: @LLIAMnYP Is there anyway that this could be done without using replacements?

Comment: How about `Solve[equations && var == x z, var]`?

Comment: OTOH that wouldn't work, a second equation seems to require a second variable to solve for, i.e. `Solve[..., {x, var}]` or such.

Comment: @Kuba or, in other words, for `a b c - d e f == 0` we have no idea what `a`, `b`, and `c` are, but we know that their product, `a b c` is equal to `d e f`.

Comment: see: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3825/5478

Comment: @Kuba it's a nice question, but quite sure, it's a dupe, maybe not of your link, but of those therein, what do you think?

Comment: @LLlAMnYP maybe one of those links is better but the question asks about replacing `z x` with `var` while the linked one `a / b` with `k`, I'd say it is close enough. But I don't have time to focus on details so I will leave the link for people judgement.

Comment: why do you need to do it without using replacements? Because that seems the natural method to do this kind of things

Comment: @glS I was just wondering if there was another or a shorter way to do it. I'm familiar with replacements so I am curious if the same behavior could be achieve with something I didn't know about

Comment: well at least in this case `Solve[eq == 0, HoldPattern@Times[x, z]]` works, but I don't know how stable of a solution this would be in more complex cases

Answer (score 2):

How about introducing the extra variable as a new equation and then telling `Solve` to solve for 2 variables? Or use `Reduce` instead?

```
Clear[x, z, y, eq];
eq = Expand[x (z + y)];
Solve[{eq == 0, xz == x z}, {xz, y}]
Reduce[{eq == 0, xz == x z}, {xz}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
eq = Expand[x (z+y)];
Reduce[eq == 0 && v == x z, v]
```

> (x == 0 && v == 0) || (y == -z && v == x z)