# Force using function definitions when simplifying

Tags: simplifying-expressions

So, I have my function, such as

```
f[x_,y_]:=(1-x/y)^(1/2);
```

This function enters a big expression that contains variables x and y, as well as the function f. Now I have to differentiate that expression with respect to either x or y (or both). Evaluating the result, Mathematica will substitute each occurrence of f[x,y] with the definition above. For this particular function, its derivative will involve the factor of

```
(1-x/y)^(-1/2),
```

i.e.

```
1/f[x,y].
```

When simplifying the result, how can I tell Mathematica to use this fact? I know there options to Simplify like TransformationFunctions, ExludedForms, ComplexityFunction, but the information and examples of the beginner-level on these options are rather scarce.

ADDENDUM

I think first I should have asked a simpler question.

```
In[1]:= Simplify[G m/r^2, G m == A]

Out[1]= A/r^2
```

But:

```
In[2]:= Simplify[G m/r^2, G m/r^2 == A]

Out[2]= G m/r^2
```

Why is output not simply A?

Comment: very closely related: [3822](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3822/can-i-simplify-an-expression-into-form-which-uses-my-own-definitions)

Answer (score 4):

Instead of giving a [`DownValues`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DownValues) for `f`, you could give definitions for it's derivative:

```
Clear[f];
f /: Derivative[1, 0][f] = -1/(2 f[#1, #2] y)&;
f /: Derivative[0, 1][f] = x / (2 f[#1, #2] y^2)&;
```

Then, the following derivatives use `f[x, y]` in the output:

```
D[f[x, y], x] //TeXForm
```

> $-\frac{1}{2 y f(x,y)}$

```
D[f[x, y], y] //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{x}{2 y^2 f(x,y)}$

```
D[f[x, y] y + f[x, z] x + f[y, x] z, x] //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{x z}{2 y^2 f(y,x)}-\frac{x}{2 y f(x,z)}-\frac{1}{2 f(x,y)}+f(x,z)$

Comment: Interesting that you get the higher derivatives for free; `D[f[x, y], {x, 2}]`.

Comment: Is there a more general way? I gave a particular example, but I need a general solution, when I have f[x_, y_]:=whatever function of x and y, and I want to replace in a given expression each combination of x and y that yields this function with the symbol f.

Answer (score 3):

You can define f this way

```
frule = {f -> (Sqrt[1 - #1/#2] &)}
```

Then use it in any expression, such as

```
D[f[x, y], x] + f[x, y] /. frule
(*Sqrt[1-x/y]-1/(2 y Sqrt[1-x/y])*)
```