# Substituting variables inside a matrix

Tags: differential-equations, matrix, replacement

I'm trying to substitute some dependent variables into equations inside of a matrix, however $Replace[]$ and and $/.$ don't seem to work.

The equation in question is just a vector matrix of differential equations, which I eventually intend to solve.

```
 NTISE = 
   {
    {((-(Ωc2^2 - I*γ*Ωo1))*a[t] + Ωd2^2*b[t] +        2*I*Ωo1*Derivative[1][a][t])/Ωo1},
    {(Ωd2^2*a[t] + (Ωc2^2 + I*γ*Ωo1)*b[t] +           2*I*Ωo1*Derivative[1][b][t])/Ωo1},
    {((-Ωc2^2 + 2*Ωe^2 + I*γ*Ωo2)*c[t] + Ωd2^2*d[t] + 2*I*Ωo2*Derivative[1][c][t])/Ωo2},
    {(Ωd2^2*c[t] + (Ωc2^2 + 2*Ωe^2 + I*γ*Ωo2)*d[t] +  2*I*Ωo2*Derivative[1][d][t])/Ωo2}
   }
```

And the expressions I would like to substitute in are

```
ΔΩ1 = Ωc2^2/Ωo1
ΔΩ2 = Ωc2^2/Ωo2
ωd1 = Ωd2^2/Ωo1
ωd2 = Ωd2^2/Ωo2
```

These expressions should simplify the DEs above in order to get equations that can then be solved, however, I tried using

```
NTISE /.
 {  Ωc2^2/Ωo1 ->  ΔΩ1,
    Ωc2^2/Ωo2 ->  ΔΩ2,
    Ωd2^2/Ωo1 ->  ωd1,
    Ωd2^2/Ωo2 ->  ωd2}
```

To no avail, and furthermore attempted

```
Replace[NTISE,
  {  Ωc2^2/Ωo1 ->  ΔΩ1,
     Ωc2^2/Ωo2 ->  ΔΩ2,
     Ωd2^2/Ωo1 ->  ωd1,
     Ωd2^2/Ωo2 ->  ωd2}, Infinity]
```

And got the same equations out.

Comment: You can kind of trick it by slightly rewriting the replacement expression and using it as a rule `NTISE /. {\[CapitalOmega]c2^2 -> \[CapitalDelta]\[CapitalOmega]1, \
\[CapitalOmega]c2^2 -> \
\[CapitalDelta]\[CapitalOmega]2*\[CapitalOmega]o2, \
\[CapitalOmega]d2^2 -> \[Omega]d1*\[CapitalOmega]o1, \
\[CapitalOmega]d2^2 -> \[Omega]d2*\[CapitalOmega]o2} // Simplify`

Comment: Im sorry, I'm not familiar with this method, could you make it clearer for me?

Comment: Specifically, I can't figure out the difference between what you wrote and what I tried

Comment: I used rules to do the replacement e.g. `a*b->c` would replace instances of a*b in the expression before the `ReplaceAll` which has a shorthand `/.`. Then I changed your replacement rules by multiplying both sides by the denominator. Instead of `\[CapitalOmega]c2^2/\[CapitalOmega]o1 -> \[CapitalDelta]\
\[CapitalOmega]1` I wrote `\[CapitalOmega]c2^2 -> \
\[CapitalDelta]\[CapitalOmega]1*\[CapitalOmega]o1`

Comment: So two questions. 1. the replaceall (/.) stays where it is in my expression? And 2. I just multiply by the denom and mathematica replaces the numerator symbol with my symbol*denom and it simplifies out to what I want it to?

Comment: If NTISE is what you want to use your replacement on then `NTISE/.{Your rules}//Simplify`. The `Simplify` function should take care of ridding you of the denominator.

Comment: I've tried this by doing         NTISE /. {  (\[CapitalOmega]c2^2) ->   \
\[CapitalDelta]\[CapitalOmega]1*\[CapitalOmega]o1 ,
    (\[CapitalOmega]c2^2) ->  \[CapitalDelta]\[CapitalOmega]2*\
\[CapitalOmega]o2 ,
     (\[CapitalOmega]d2^2) ->  \[Omega]d1*\[CapitalOmega]o1,
     (\[CapitalOmega]d2^2) ->  \[Omega]d2*\[CapitalOmega]o2} and it still doesn't give the right answer

Comment: I am unsure what the right answer is, but it replaces all instances where `\[CapitalOmega]c2^2` and other squared omegas occur and make the first two expressions somewhat simpler.

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps we're using different mathematica editions - 11.2 here. By the right answer I meant one where the variables are substituted into the equations

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3822/121 ?

Answer (score 2):

By expanding `NTISE` the denominators are distributed among individual terms, so that `ReplaceAll` rules match the denominators once per rule.

```
Simplify[Expand[NTISE] /.
 {  Ωc2^2/Ωo1 -> ΔΩ1,
    Ωc2^2/Ωo2 -> ΔΩ2,
    Ωd2^2/Ωo1 -> ωd1,
    Ωd2^2/Ωo2 -> ωd2}]
```

returns:

> ```
> {
>    {I (γ + I ΔΩ1) a[t] + ωd1 b[t] + 2 I a'[t]},
>    {ωd1 a[t] + (I γ + ΔΩ1) b[t] + 2 I b'[t]},
>    {(I γ - ΔΩ2 + (2 Ωe^2)/Ωo2) c[t] + ωd2 d[t] + 2 I c'[t]},
>    {ωd2 c[t] + (I γ + ΔΩ2 + (2 Ωe^2)/Ωo2) d[t] + 2 I d'[t]}
> }
> ```

For example, looking at the first term of `NTISE`,

$$
\frac{-\left(\text{$\Omega $c2}^2 + i \gamma \text{$\Omega $o1}\right)a[t] + \text{$\Omega $d2}^2 b[t]+2 i \text{$\Omega $o1} a'[t]}{\text{$\Omega $o1}}
$$

expanding the expression gives:

$$
i \gamma  a[t]-\frac{\text{$\Omega $c2}^2 a[t]}{\text{$\Omega $o1}}+\frac{\text{$\Omega $d2}^2 b[t]}{\text{$\Omega $o1}} + 2 i a'[t]
$$

which allows `ReplaceAll` to match the rules `Ωc2^2/Ωo1 -> ΔΩ1` and `Ωd2^2/Ωo1 -> ωd1`.