# Assign a variable to an expression in Mathematica

Tags: matrix, variable-definitions

I have the following matrix

```
    {{a^2 + b + \[Sqrt](m + n) + 5, 23 x + 7 a}, {14 b, 
  a^2 + b + \[Sqrt](m - n) + 5}}
```

I want to replace the expressions `a^2 + b + \[Sqrt](m + n) + 5` by $A$ and `a^2 + b + \[Sqrt](m - n) + 5` by $B$, not by hand, but by letting Mathematica to do it for me.

Comment: try `ReplaceAll`: e.g. `mat  /. {a^2 + b + \[Sqrt](m + n) + 5 -> A, 
  a^2 + b + \[Sqrt](m - n) + 5 -> B}`?

Comment: or, maybe, `A = mat[[1, 1]]; B = mat[[2, 2]];`?

Comment: Answers linked in this topic should address this problem: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3822/5478