# Do replacement only on certain specific forms

Tags: replacement, expression-manipulation

If I want to replace, say, `a` with `a1 + a2` in an expression, I can write

```
expr /. a -> a1 + a2
```

But what about the opposite?

In some cases it might just be a matter of inverting things, such as the following substitutions

$\qquad \phi=\varphi_{1}+\varphi_{2},\quad \delta=\varphi_{1}-\varphi_{2}$

which can be inverted by solving for $\varphi_1,\, \varphi_2$ and then just using `/.`

But what about something more complex like this:

```
Sin[a + c] + Sin[c](Cos[b + c]a + Sin[Cos[a + c] + a*b]) + Log[a + b + c]
```

Let's say that I want to replace every instance of the expression `a + b + c` with `S`, and leave unchanged all the other expressions in which `a, b` or `c` appear but not in the form `a + b + c`.

How should I do this?

Comment: See [3822](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3822/5478) and links in Mr.Wizard's answer. Is that what you need?