# Is there a way to use identities in Mathematica efficiently?

Tags: functions, number-representation

Imagine I have defined a variable
`l=p/(a*b)`
Let's say I perform some operations, and I get the final answer to be `p/a`.
But all I really care about is how this expression looks in terms of `l` and `b`. Is there a way to use the relation `l=p/(a*b)` to convert `p/a` to `l/b`?

Of course this is a very trivial example, it gets trickier when you have other, more complicated relations. I have tried the replace command `/.{p/(a*b) -> l}` but it does not work.

I would appreciate any advice you have!

Comment: `p/a /. First@ Solve[l == p/(a*b), p]`?

Comment: If you `Set` the value of `l` with the expression `l = p/(a*b)` then `l` cannot appear in an output cell since it will evaluate to `p/(a*b)`

Comment: `Clear[l]; p/a /. p->l*a*b`

Comment: See for example [this MSE thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3822/can-i-simplify-an-expression-into-form-which-uses-my-own-definitions)

Answer (score 0):

Once you have your answer, `ans`, you can `Unset` variable `l` and use it in subsequent expressions, to get a new answer, like this

```
Clear[a, b, l, p]

l = p/(a*b);

ans = p/a;

auxEqn = l == (l =.; l);

newAns = ans /. First@Solve[auxEqn, p]   (*  bl  *)
```

Now `newAns` evaluates to `b*l` and `l` no longer has a value.  If you want to recover the value of `l` from `auxEqn`, do this

```
Set @@ Reverse@auxEqn;
l   
  (*  p / (a b)  *)
```

But, if you do that, `newAns` will evaluate to `p/a`. Unless you `Unset[l]` (same as `l=.`) again, in which case `newAns` will evaluate to `b*l`.

If you were really going to do something like this, consider starting with `auxEqn = l == p/(a*b)`.  Then you would `Set@@auxEqn` to set the value of `l`, do the calculations that need `l` to have a value, and `l=.` to unset the value. Once `l` is unset, use `Solve[newEqn, p]` to replace parameter `p` with its equivalent expression involving `l`.