# How to simplify expression depending on former definition?

Tags: evaluation, variable-definitions

If

```
a = x + y

b = x - y

u = a + b

v = a
```

This gives me for `u/v` the expression `(2 x)/(x + y)`
But I want to get `1+b/a`. How to do that when `a` and `b` are very long expressions?

Comment: Why does it matter if `a` and `b` are long expressions if you just want `1+b/a`?

Comment: Or are you saying you want `1 + (x-y)/(x+y)`?

Comment: 1+b/a is ok, I just wanted to avoid long Replace answers. I was looking for some kind of short switch (from x,y to a,b), because I have many variables to deal with. I was looking sore something like Eliminate, but that works only for equations.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I simplify an expression into form which uses my own definitions?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3822/can-i-simplify-an-expression-into-form-which-uses-my-own-definitions)

Comment: I found that the following works
`eq1 = a == x + y;
eq2 = b == x - y;
eq3 = u == a + b;
eq4 = v == a;
eq5 = c == u/v;
sol = Eliminate[{eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4, eq5}, {x, y, u, v}];
Solve[sol, c]`
Which looks very clumsy. Any better ideas?

Comment: What are you going to do with the 1+b/a expression? If you just want to see it, you can use one of the Hold forms (for example).

Comment: Lericr, How would I do it then with Hold forms? I want to use different forms by which you can describe triangles (by a,b,c or angles or other parts once coordinates are given)

Answer (score 3):

```
u/v /. u -> a + b /. v -> a // Apart
```