# Representing a value in an output as a self defined variable

Tags: symbolic, variable-definitions, replacement

I'm trying to find a way to have Mathematica always represent a numerical value as a self defined variable that I define using `lhs=rhs`. For example, if I execute

```
In[1]:=Solve[x^3 - 1 == 0, x]
Out[1]:={{x -> 1}, {x -> -(-1)^(1/3)}, {x -> (-1)^(2/3)}}
```

What I'd like is to define a variable `rho=(-1)^(1/3)` so that when I execute the above I get out something like

```
In[1]:=Solve[x^3 - 1 == 0, x]
Out[1]:={{x -> 1}, {x -> -rho}, {x -> rho^2}}
```

Is this possible? I'm basically trying to get mathematica to always represent an $n$th root of unity as a given symbol to clean up inputs and outputs.

Comment: David, if you register and link your account with your math.se profile, you'll start with 101 rep and you'll have access to other basic functionalities of the site

Comment: @R.M Thanks for the tip! I didn't realize I had to do that.

Comment: Also, I assume you're looking for a general solution and not just for the cube roots, right? i.e., if you type `Solve[x^n -1 == 0, x]`, you get `{1, r, r^2, ..., r^n-1}`?

Comment: @R.M Well, a general solution would be kinda neat, that's a little more than I'd had in mind. I was just thinking I could define a symbol for say the primitive 3rd root of unity and have mathematica replace (-1)^{1/3} with that symbol whenever it appears.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My solution below uses [`TagSetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TagSetDelayed.html) and associates the transformation rules with `Power`. Although [I very much dislike](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3465/5) using structural manipulations for such purposes, it might be a viable option here since the use case is narrow.

```
Unprotect[Power]
Power /: Power[-1, Rational[n_Integer, _]] := ρ^n
Protect[Power]
```

[image]

[image]

If you want to define it *only* for the cube roots of unity, you needn't use a general pattern like the above. Instead, restrict it by changing the `_` to `3`.

Answer (score 4):

The most basic form of this could be implemented as a replacement rule in `$Post`:

```
$Post = # /. (-1)^(1/3) -> rho &;
```

As you can see however this doesn't handle the compound case:

```
Solve[x^3 - 1 == 0, x]
```

> ```
> {{x -> 1}, {x -> -rho}, {x -> (-1)^(2/3)}}
> ```

If it is sufficient to include various specific cases in your replacement rules function (`$Post`) then this should be a solution.  If you need to "find" the expression within a compound one, I believe you can adapt and integrate [Daniel's `PolynomialReduce` method](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/571/121).

Comment: While accepted R.M.'s answer for being the most generalizable solution to my issue. I just wanted to mention that your solution is easiest to implement and ended up being the one that I used for my particular task.