# How to substitute the following conditions into an expression?

Tags: equation-solving, output-formatting, polynomials, algebraic-manipulation

I have an expression: $p=a\;b\; x + b^2\; y + a\;c\; z$. I want to substitute $a\;b=1$, $b^2 = 2$ and $a\;c = 4$ to obtain $p = x + 2y + 4z$.
How can I tell *Mathematica* to do that? I dont know how to start.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A reliable approach would use the third argument of `Reduce` as variables to eliminate (see [Behavior of Reduce with variables as domain](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41247/behavior-of-reduce-with-variables-as-domain))

```
Reduce[{p == a b x + b^2 y + a c z, a b == 1, b^2 == 2, a c == 4}, {p}, {a, b, c}]
```

> ```
> p == x + 2 y + 4 z
> ```

In the former editions of *Mathematica* (`ver <= 4`) [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v4/RefGuide/Reduce.html) used the third argument for eliminating another variables. It can be still used this way though it is not documented anymore, however  its trace could be found in `SystemOptions["ReduceOptions"]`.
If `Reduce` didn't work this way one would exploit `Solve` (it is still supposed to [eliminate variables](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/EliminatingVariables.html)), e.g.:

```
Apply[ Equal, Solve[{p == a b x + b^2 y + a c z, a b == 1, b^2 == 2, a c == 4}, 
       {p}, {a, b, c}], {2}][[1, 1]]
```

or `Eliminate`:

```
Eliminate[{p == a b x + b^2 y + a c z, a b == 1, b^2 == 2, a c == 4}, 
          {a, b, c}] // Reverse
```

or even simply appropriate rules replacement (in general this approach cannot be used seamlessly though)

```
p == a b x + b^2 y + a c z /. {a b -> 1, b^2 -> 2, a c -> 4} // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

**Edit**

It would be reasonable to mention another two functions useful in similar tasks. Taking this polynomial identiclly equal to zero:

```
poly = p - a b x - b^2 y - a c z;
```

we can rewrite it in terms of another three polynomials which are also identically zeros by the assumptions:

```
{poly1, poly2, poly3} = {a b - 1, b^2 - 2, a c - 4};
```

thus we know that the resulting polynomial will be equal to zero as well:

```
Last @ PolynomialReduce[ poly, {poly1, poly2, poly3}, {a, b, c, p, x, y, z}] == 0
```

> ```
> p - x - 2 y - 4 z == 0
> ```

similarily we can find a Groebner basis of polynomials `{ poly, poly1, poly2, poly3}` eliminating unwanted variables `{a, b, c}`:

```
First @ GroebnerBasis[{ poly, poly1, poly2, poly3}, {x, y, z}, {a, b, c},
                       MonomialOrder -> EliminationOrder] == 0
```

These two methods are more useful when we want to  find different representations of (polynomial) expressions in polynomial rings, thus we needn't assume that polynomials `{ poly, poly1, poly2, poly3}` identically vanish.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar without eliminating the variables, i.e., just replace certain polynomials in an expression, so that the result is more compact and easier to read. Is there any way to do this with Mathematica?

Comment: Try to formulate your problem as a separate question, otherwise it is hard to guess what you are trying to do.