# Rule can not work?

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching, semantic-matching

For example I have this equation,I want to use c->a/b ,but it can not work
$$
\frac{a^2}{b^2}+\frac{b^2}{a^2}+\frac{a}{b}+e^{a/b}+\frac{b}{a}+\log \left(\frac{a}{b}\right)
$$

```mathematica
rule = {a/b -> c};
eq = 1/(a/b)^2 + (a/b)^2 + 1/(a/b) + a/b + Exp[a/b] + Log[a/b];
eq /. rule
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, here's a properer possible duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3822/1871

Comment: Since you can read Chinese, check this also: http://note.youdao.com/noteshare?id=77b86cb08aaf29ce8747990c9e717298

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us write down the same rule in other formula.

```
rule ={a -> c*b};eq = 1/(a/b)^2 + (a/b)^2 + 1/(a/b) + a/b + Exp[a/b] + Log[a/b];eq /. rule
```

> `1/c^2 + 1/c + c + c^2 + E^c + Log[c]`

Similar questions were asked and answered here many,many times.

Comment: Don't quite understand why you would do that?

Comment: @我心永恒 it is easier to replace one `Symbol` than an expression that can be manipulated like `a/b`. Case in point, Mathematica doesn't see `a^2 / b^2` as `(a/b)^2` for structural replacements as done with `/.`

Comment: @b3m2a1 Sometimes my expressions get complicated what do I do?

Comment: @我心永恒 the best thing is to rewrite your rules so they are replacements of a variable by e.g. solving for `a` in `c = a/b`. If that fails you _might_ be able to add rules to `Simplify` using some of the techniques discussed on the site

Comment: @b3m2a1 Maybe it has to be this way

Comment: @我心永恒 there are probably lots of methods but you can consider for example the links provided as duplicate or this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/274117/86543) or the linked post in the first answer of that last link. Basically, `/. expression1->expression2` uses pattern matching and a looot can go wrong with pattern matching in expressions. If you want to substitute something complicated by something else, using equation solving is more robust/safe/reliable.

Answer (score 4):

- We need to use `Hold` to prevent MMA evaluate the `eq`.

```
rule = {a/b -> c};
Hold[1/(a/b)^2 + (a/b)^2 + 1/(a/b) + a/b + Exp[a/b] + Log[a/b]] /. rule
ReleaseHold[%]
```

[image]

- Or simple using

```
Block[{a = b*c}, a^2/b^2 + a/b + b/a + b^2/a^2 + E^(a/b) + Log[a/b]]
```

[image]

Comment: I know that rule is replaced by `pattern`, simple and practical c->a/b is not acceptable, but in many cases it is difficult to find `pattern`. What is the principle of using `hold`? I don't understand

Comment: @rhermans  Thanks, updated.

Answer (score 4):

To see why Mathematica does what it does, it can be instructive to write out the `FullForm` of the expressions in question.  This tells you how Mathematica is storing these things internally.

```
FullForm[rule]
(* List[Rule[Times[a,Power[b,-1]],c]] *)
```

So what Mathematica is doing when it applies `rule` is replacing all internal instances of `Times[a, Power[b, -1]]` with `c`.  Notably, it will not replace sub-expressions that do not literally match this expression.

If we look at `Fullform[eq]`, we can see why some of the expressions get replaced and others don't:

```
FullForm[eq]
(* Plus[
    Times[Power[a,2],Power[b,-2]],
    Times[a,Power[b,-1]],
    Times[Power[a,-1],b],
    Times[Power[a,-2],Power[b,2]],
    Power[E,Times[a,Power[b,-1]]],
    Log[Times[a,Power[b,-1]]]
] *)
```

From this, you can see that three of the summands in `eq` actually contain the literal expression `Times[a,Power[b,-1]]`, and so Mathematica replaces those with `c`.  In contrast, the other three summands do not contain this expression and so Mathematica leaves them alone when `rule` is applied.

In contrast, if you define `rule2 = {a -> c*b}`, as suggested by [user64494](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/277061/27813), then internally Mathematica views this rule as

```
List[Rule[a,Times[b,c]]]
```

which means that it will replace the expression `a` with `Times[b,c]` everywhere it occurs.  This gets *all* of the `a` expressions, even those embedded inside other expressions involving `Times`, `Power`, etc.  This is why it's general best to write replacement rules with a single symbol on the left-hand side;  if you have a more complicated expression on the left-hand side, you're not guaranteed that Mathematica will replace everything you want it to replace.

Alternately, applying `Hold` to an expression (as suggested by [cvgmt](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/277063/27813) prevents Mathematica from doing internal "simplification" and keeps things in the same form you literally entered them:

```
holdeq = Hold[1/(a/b)^2 + (a/b)^2 + 1/(a/b) + a/b + Exp[a/b] + Log[a/b]];
FullForm[holdeq]

(* Hold[
     Plus[
      Times[1,Power[Power[Times[a,Power[b,-1]],2],-1]], 
      Power[Times[a,Power[b,-1]],2], 
      Times[1,Power[Times[a,Power[b,-1]],-1]], 
      Times[a,Power[b,-1]],Exp[Times[a,Power[b,-1]]], 
      Log[Times[a,Power[b,-1]]]
     ]
   ] *)
```

With the `Hold` present, Mathematica does not apply any simplification rules, leaving the expression `Times[a,Power[b,-1]]` in its original form;  and so when `rule` is applied, it successfully replaces all of the instances.