# What is the simplest way to proceed when a rule does not match?

Tags: replacement

This rule works fine, of course:

```
a x + b /. a x + b -> z
(* z *)
```

However, this one does not:

```
a x + b /. -a x - b -> -z
(* b + a x *)
```

I understand that when one expands the expressions using FullForm the patterns do not match.

This works:

```
w /. Solve[w == a x + b && z == -a x - b, {w}, {a, x, b}][[1]]
(* -z *)
```

But it looks way too complicated. Is there a smarter way?

(Of course in this particular example there is an obvious solution: the first command shown above. Let us assume the perfectly matching pattern is not known)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Use `PolynomialReduce`. `In[9]:= PolynomialReduce[a x + b, {-a x - b + z}, {a, b}][[2]]

Out[9]= z`

Comment: Not sure if this helps but you can also use FullSimplify:
`FullSimplify[ax + b, Assumptions -> (-ax - b == -z)]`

Comment: Or even simpler: `Simplify[ax + b, (-ax - b == -z)]`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau - Thanks, it works! I saw a "2" besides your comment. Can I accept a comment?

Comment: @FrankMartin - Thanks for the suggestions, but neither one of them works if you change the sign of z. For example,

Comment: @FernandoSaldanha Much as I appreciate the gesture, the fact is that this is likely to be closed as a duplicate.  See [1](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/552/how-do-i-replace-a-variable-in-a-polynomial) or [2](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/894/replace-expressions-with-symbols) or [3](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42121/how-to-substitute-the-following-conditions-into-an-expression) (and there are some others as well).

Comment: @FrankMartin - Thanks for the suggestions, but neither one of them works. I had a*x +b, not ax+b, but even independently of that, if you change the sign in front of z you get back ax+b. For example, Simplify[ax + b, (-ax - b == z)] returns ax+b.

Comment: @FernandoSaldanha `Simplify[a*x + b, -a*x - b == -z]` returns 'z' for me and also `Simplify[a*x + b, -a*x - b == z]` returns '-z' for me. Could you please check that? (I'm working in Mathematica 11)

Comment: @FrankMartin Indeed, with '*'between the a and the x, Simplify[a*x + b, -a*x - b == -z] returns 'z' and also Simplify[a*x + b, -a*x - b == z] returns '-z'. However, (mysteriously, at least for me), without a * between the z and the x, Simplify[ax + b, (-ax - b == z)] returns 'ax + b'. I am also using Mathematica 11.

Comment: @FrankMartin  Sorry for the mess in my previous comment. There is a problem with the asterisk character. What I wanted to say is that with an asterisk between the a and the x, meaning Times[a,x],  both commands work fine. However, without the asterisk, that is, with variable ax, one of them does not, that is, Simplify[ax + b, -ax - b == z] returns ax+b. I quit the kernel and restarted it before evaluating this.

Comment: @FernandoSaldanha, Thanks for your time to reply. I'm a bit confused why it doesn't work. Might get back to that later.