# How to let mathematica "recognize" expressions?

Tags: replacement

I will explain my problem with an example.

I have : $Cj=j(j+1)$ and $dj=(2*j+1)$

In mathematica I have a variable "a" that is equal to : $j(j+1)(2*j+1)$

How can I tell him to recognize that $a$ is in fact equal to $Cj*dj$. So I want him to write $Cj*dj$ instead of  $j(j+1)(2*j+1)$.

In fact, each time he "see" a term $j(j+1)$, he will understand that he has to replace it by $cj$ (and same for $dj$).

I did the following :

```
In[3]:= Solve[ppp == J (1 + J) && x = J (J + 1), {ppp}, {x}]
```

But mathematica answers me :

```
Set::write: Tag And in ppp==J (1+J)&&x is Protected.

Solve::naqs: \!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Exists]\), \({x}\)]\(J\ \((1 + J)\)\)\) is not a quantified system of equations and inequalities.
```

I saw this method from here :

[How do I replace a variable in a polynomial?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/552/how-do-i-replace-a-variable-in-a-polynomial)

Why it doesn't work and how to do it ?

Comment: Because you assign instead of comparing (`=` vs `==`).

Comment: Oh, indeed, thanks