# Why my solve doesn't work?

Tags: equation-solving

I want mathematica to recognize an expression. Thus I followed the ideas developed [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/552/how-do-i-replace-a-variable-in-a-polynomial) and I wrote :

```
Solve[polynomelhs == 
  1/3 (1 + 2 J) (3 J + 3 J^2 + j4 + j4^2) (J + J^2 + 3 j4 + 3 j4^2) && 
  Cj4 == j4*(j4 + 1)  && CJ == J (J + 1) && DJ == 2*J + 1, 
  {polynomelhs}, {j4}, {J}]
```

I want that mathematica answers me `polynomelhs->(1/3)*DJ*(3*CJ+Cj4)(CJ+3Cj4)`

But it does'nt work.

I even cleared all my variables just before the solve but it doesn't work still.

Why isn't it working ?

The error is : `Solve::bddom: Value {J} of the domain argument should be Complexes, Reals, Algebraics, Rationals, Integers, Primes, or Automatic.`

I never needed to specify the domain argument before so why do I need to do it now ?

Comment: Your syntax for the `Solve` command is incorrect.  I think your set of equations may have more than one solution.

Comment: Your 3rd argument `{J}` is in the position where `Solve` expects a domain specification, which explains the error message you see.

Answer (score 2):

```
eqns = polynomelhs == 
    1/3 (1 + 2 J) (3 J + 3 J^2 + j4 + j4^2) (J + J^2 + 3 j4 + 
       3 j4^2) && Cj4 == j4*(j4 + 1) && CJ == J (J + 1) && 
   DJ == 2*J + 1;
```

Use [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html) rather than [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html). Note that the variables to be eliminated must be in a single list. The fourth argument in your `Solve` was interpreted as an invalid domain specification.

```
sol = Reduce[eqns, polynomelhs, {j4, J}] // ToRules

(*  {CJ -> 1/4 (-1 + DJ^2), 
 polynomelhs -> 
  1/48 DJ (3 - 40 Cj4 + 48 Cj4^2 - 6 DJ^2 + 40 Cj4 DJ^2 + 3 DJ^4)}  *)
```

[`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) the expression for `polynomelhs` using the solution given for `CJ` as an assumption

```
FullSimplify[polynomelhs /. sol, Equal @@ sol[[1]]]

(*  1/3 (3 CJ + Cj4) (CJ + 3 Cj4) DJ  *)
```

**EDIT:** `Solve` will work if you specify that you also want to know the variable `CJ`

```
sol2 = Solve[eqns, {polynomelhs, CJ}, {j4, J}][[1]]

(*  {polynomelhs -> 
  1/48 DJ (3 - 40 Cj4 + 48 Cj4^2 - 6 DJ^2 + 40 Cj4 DJ^2 + 3 DJ^4), 
 CJ -> 1/4 (-1 + DJ^2)}  *)

FullSimplify[polynomelhs /. sol2, Equal @@ sol2[[2]]]

(*  1/3 (3 CJ + Cj4) (CJ + 3 Cj4) DJ  *)
```

Comment: Why is reduce better than solve in this case ? Thank you !!

Comment: @StarBucK - The algorithms used by `Reduce` are more powerful and handle more cases than those used by `Solve`. When `Solve` didn't work with the input, I tried adding the option `Method-> Reduce`, and when that didn't work I switched to `Reduce`. "If at first you don't succeed, get a bigger hammer."